# Write lock using WebClient.DownloadFileAsync()

Tags: c#, readwritelock

I'm having a problem with a web system of mine, and I believe that it is because of some read/write locks happening on a file. If a file is open and needs to be written to, it'll cause the process to lock up and freeze parts of my system. That is all speculation, but with the result of empty files, I believe this is the cause.

I use the following code in my application, where `url` is a string of the URL to download, and `file` is a string of the location to save the downloaded content to. With my following code, is there a way I can have it check to see if the file is open/in use and only write to it when it is able to be written to?

```
using (WebClient Client = new WebClient())
{
    Uri uri = new Uri(url);
    Client.DownloadFileAsync(uri, file);
    result = true;
}
```

Sorry if there is something else going on, or I'm missing something. Thank you so much!

Comment: Probably not related to your issue, but have realised you're disposing the WebClient before download finishes?

Comment: It looks like your're getting empty files. The unsing statement maybe the cause. Have you tried without it?